# The backup failed, but the response was: Success. Is this a bug?

Tags: database, cnosdb

I used cnosdb-imexport to perform data backup as follows:

```
cnosdb-enterprise git:(main) ✗ ./target/release/cnosdb-imexport export -s root:@127.0.0.1:8912 --path /xxx/backup/
```

The log printed during the backup process is as follows：

```
# Input args: Cli { subcmd: Export(ExportArgs { src: "root:@127.0.0.1:8912", path: "/Users/bichaoxue/Documents/github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb-enterprise/backup/", conn: None }) }
# Begin  export table(cnosdb.public.air)  [Now: 18:37:12]
# Export table(cnosdb.public.air) data: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: IO error: No such file or directory (os error 2)"}
...
# Begin  export table(cnosdb.usage_schema.vnode_disk_storage)  [Now: 18:37:12]
# Export table(cnosdb.usage_schema.vnode_disk_storage) data: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: IO error: No such file or directory (os error 2)"}
```

but the result is succeed.

```
# Export  Data: Ok(())
```

and I searched for data under the specified path, and the directory was also empty.

```
cnosdb-enterprise git:(main) ✗ ll /xxx/backup/
total 0
```

What's going on? Has anyone encountered it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After communicating with the community, we found that it is indeed a bug, and we will fix it later [github](https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/issues/1862#issuecomment-1867573925)